# AsyncContext and I/O error handling (when peer disconnects)

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jetty, comet, servlet-3.0

I'm implementing Server-Sent Events using Servlet 3.0's [javax.servlet.AsyncContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) interface.

However I can't understand how I should handle I/O errors like peer disconnect.

For a given `AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync()`, I can call `ac.getResponse().getWriter().print(something)` and then `ac.getResponse.getWriter().flush()` and it works fine. However when a client disconnects, I don't get an error - even if I attach a listener, its `onError` method is not called.

I tested it with both Jetty 8 and Tomcat 7 and it seems that the disconnect from the client is not reported back to the application.

What can be done to detect a communication error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that: `ac.getResponse.getWriter().flush()` does not throw `IOException`

So in order to get a error notification upon I/O operation you need to use `ServletOutputStream` instead:

```
try {
   ServletOutputStream out = ac.getResponse().getOutputStream();
   out.print(stuff);
   out.flush(); // throws IOException
}
catch(IOException e) {
   // handle a error
}
```

Comment: just a small addition, in my case `out.flush();` raised the `IOException` only after `AsyncContext` called `onTimeout()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative solution, in cases where it's more convenient to use `getWriter()`.

```
PrintWriter out = ac.getResponse().getWriter();
out.print(stuff);
out.flush(); // swallows IOException
if (out.checkError()) {
   // handle error or throw out...
}
```

That is, the PrintWriter class does provide a method to retrieve write errors later.