# AsyncContext Servlet 3.0 client disconnect

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

I'm trying to implement Server-Sent Events using Servlet 3.0 AsyncContext.

But when the client is disconnected the exception is not called.

PrintWriter writer = ctx.getResponse().getWriter();
writer.println(json);                               ctx.getResponse().flushBuffer();

This post is same as the problem here: [AsyncContext and I/O error handling (when peer disconnects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039939/asynccontext-and-error-handling)